# Probability to seat at the same table in a poker tournament.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Warning**. This question is inspired by the ongoing Main Event of the Word Series of Poker, but it is a purely mathematical question and requires no knowledge of poker.

Consider a poker tournament with $N = 10000$ players. The $N$ players are ranked (randomly) from $1$ to $N$ and have uniform equity: for each $k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$, each player has probability $1/N$ to finish the tournament in $k$-th position. The tournament goes as follows: players are gathered in $N/10 = 1000$ tables (numbered from $1$ to $N/10$) of $10$ players each: Table $1$ gathers players $1$ to $10$, Table $2$ gathers players $11$ to $20$ and so on.

Each time $10$ players are eliminated, the tables are filled again according to the following process: if there were $K$ remaining tables (numbered from $1$ to $K$), the players of Table $K$ are used to fill the remaining $K - 1$ tables, starting from Table $1$, up to Table $K-1$. After this step, there are again $K-1$ full tables of $10$ players$^{(*)}$.  The tournament finishes when there is only one remaining player, the winner.

**Question**. Two friends register for this tournament. What is the probability that they seat at the same table at some point of the tournament?

$^{(*)} \scriptsize\text{If you need a more precise algorithm, let us say that the players fill the tables in decreasing rank order.}$

Comment: I assume that player elimination happens randomly to the players.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by uniform equity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume table refilling occurs randomly (which makes the problem simpler compared to refilling by rank!).

The probability of meeting immediately in a tournament with $T$ tables of size $S$ is $\frac {S-1}{ST-1}$. If this does not happen, the friends are at different tables $1\le a<b\le T$, and nothing of interest happens until the table count is about to decrease from $b$ to $b-1$.
Assuming that the two have survived so far (probability of this: $\frac{Sb\choose 2}{ST\choose 2}$), the friend from table $b$ is assigned to a random position at the other tables, so the friends meet with probability $\frac{S-1}{S(b-1)-1}$. In fact, we may consider this as a new tournament with $b-1$ tables.

Thus if $f(T)$ denotes the desired probability, we have
$$\begin{align}f(T)& =\frac{S-1}{ST-1}+\sum_{b=2}^T\frac{S\cdot (b-1)S}{ST\choose 2}f(b-1)\\&=\frac{S-1}{ST-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{T-1}\frac{kSf(k)}{T(ST-1)}.\end{align}$$
Numerically, with $S=10$, we find $f(1000)\approx 0.006896773971525475279786665979649$.